# column must appear in group by clause error in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that its a common problem in postgresql but i have tried many solutions on stackoverflow but did not get result, that's why i have posted this on SO.

This is my query which i am running on phpPGAdmin query browser.

```
SELECT target_financial_advisor,
   acquiror_finanial_advisor,
   target_nation,
   acquiror_nation,
   rank_value,
   rank_date
FROM ma_global
WHERE target_nation = 'France'
   AND acquiror_nation = 'France'
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR
          FROM "rank_date") = 2013
   AND rank_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY target_financial_advisor,
     acquiror_finanial_advisor LIMIT 50;
```

This query does not work if i use group by clause but if i run it without groupby then it works, don't know what the reason is , i usually work in mysql , this is my first query in postgresql, its working fine in mysql.

Error is

> ERROR:  column "ma_global.target_nation" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 4:     target_nation,
>   acquiror_nation,

Comment: "rank_date" is fine ?

Comment: yes, even i remove the rank_date condition, still same issue

Comment: The error is clear: if you do grouping every return value must be either used in an aggregate or appear in the grouping selector. If you have 200 different values in target_nation, which one should be returned? You don't specify. This is not MySQL, this is a proper database.

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` clause allows mixing of ordinary and aggregate columns in the `SELECT` clause, where `GROUP BY` must contain all result columns which are not aggregations. To make your statement correct, you can put `target_nation, acquiror_nation, rank_value, rank_date` into the `GROUP BY` clause, too. But removing this clause would be easier, because you have no aggregations. If you get duplicate rows, you should add a `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT target_financial_advisor,
    acquiror_finanial_advisor,
    target_nation,
    acquiror_nation,
    rank_value,
    rank_date
FROM ma_global
WHERE target_nation = 'France'
    AND acquiror_nation = 'France'
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR
        FROM "rank_date") = 2013
    AND rank_date IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Oh no, is this the main reason, i have been working on this issue for last four hours, Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, because you have 6 columns in select and grouping by 2 columns... This 'poor old postgres' doesn't know what you want to do with other 4 columns... If you're using group by all columns have to appear in group by or in some aggregate function. If you're not interested in what is in this four columns (or you know it since they are in WHERE clause) remove it from select... It's fundamental SQL rules.

This will work:

```
SELECT target_financial_advisor,
   acquiror_finanial_advisor,
   target_nation,
   acquiror_nation,
   rank_value,
   rank_date
FROM ma_global
WHERE target_nation = 'France'
   AND acquiror_nation = 'France'
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR
          FROM "rank_date") = 2013
   AND rank_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6 LIMIT 50;
```

or if ommiting columns from WHERE clause:

```
SELECT target_financial_advisor,
   acquiror_finanial_advisor,
   rank_value
FROM ma_global
WHERE target_nation = 'France'
   AND acquiror_nation = 'France'
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR
          FROM "rank_date") = 2013
   AND rank_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3 LIMIT 50;
```